# What is the analog of RxJava onErrorResumeNext operator in RxSwift?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I need to  emit a sequence of items if it encounters an error in RxSwift. In JAVA it can be done with "onErrorResumeNext" operator. But I can not find the same operator or its substitute in Swift.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use

```
ObservableType.catchError(handler: (ErrorType) throws -> Observable<E>) -> Observable<E>
```

Documentation can be found [here](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/RxSwift/2.2.0/Protocols/ObservableType.html#/s:FeRq_7RxSwift14ObservableType_S_S0_10catchErroruRq_S0__Fq_FFzPSs9ErrorType_GCS_10Observableqq_S0_1E_GS2_qq_S0_1E_).

Comment: It's a shame reactivex website still has those `TBA` in doc for RxSwift. I've tried to find where we could contribute documentation links for them to update the website, with no luck thus far.